# Failed to unlink socket file [MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, sudo

I am new to MongoDB & I am trying to install MongoDb-community@4.2 to use mongo on Mac, I proceeded to all these steps by steps :

> `sudo brew install mongodb`

> `mkdir -p /data/db`

> `sudo chown -R -un' /data/db`

> `mongo` or `mongod`

until i got this on terminal :

````
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:19:25.376+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:19:25.377+01:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:19:25.377+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:19:25.377+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
mac@macs-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.974+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.974+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.974+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.974+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":69610,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Users/mac/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"macs-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.1.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.976+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/Users/mac/data/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.977+01:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.977+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T20:21:23.977+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}```
````

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most probably you missed to shutdown properly your mongod previous time so there is socket file left in the tmp folder that you need to remove manually before you try to start the mongod process again:

```
    rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: i got this now : `MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1`

Comment: Is the mongod running ? Are you attempting to connect from same machine?

Comment: what do you say about "same machine" ??

Comment: any messages in the mongod logs , is it running?

Comment: I just kill all terminal running and open new one to type `mongo`, it just that i made it

Comment: when i type `mongod` i receive this again : `091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-08T23:45:29.171+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me if as  Ubuntu User.

```
     rm -f /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: to identify the problem , rum this command in the terminal : `  sudo cat/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.           i got this  message  : { "msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}. Then I removed the file